# Impossible to display the image uploaded with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to save the data that the user enter in the form, in the database like this :

images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'home2'
  #before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    #@image1 = Image.new(params[:image_filename])
    #
    if @image.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your creation has been uploaded"
      redirect_to "/showcase"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your creation has not been uploaded"
      render :new
    end
end

    private

    def image_params
      params.permit(:title, :description, :nickname, :creation)
    end
end
```

But, it try to send the data in bases before I press the submit button.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<%= image_tag @image.creation.creation_url(:thumb) %>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but creation is a variable, an error appear, with this

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create an instance of Image with `params[:images]` and that param's value is empty.

Try changing this on images_controller.rb

```
def create
  @image = Image.new(post_params)
  if @image.save
    #redirect somewhere. You didn't create a route for `show` or `edit`.
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, an other error appear : param is missing or the value is empty: image

Comment: I changed it, with       params.permit(:title, :description, :nickname, :creation), the error disappear but I still can't load the image :(

Comment: That's odd. `:image` should be in the params. Did you check the logs to see which params the form is submitting? Also, you shouldn't forget to persist the image record. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think, i know where the problem come from, from my databases, when I want to save an entry from Image instance in rails console, i simply can't save manually : http://hpics.li/9172855

Comment: I put a route to show, like you say, but my problem now is that, it redirecting me before I click on submit button so I can't even see the page with the form because it redirect me instantly in the show page. he is ignoring the button submit. so most of the time the form is empty.

Comment: You didn't have to create a whole new route for `show`. It's best to stick with the REST routes rails creates for you. You had `resources :images, only: [:new, :create]`. Adding a `show` there or even removing the `only` restriction would be best. It think you should keep the source for your controller, model, views (new,show) and routes files in your question. It's hard to figure out whats happening without them.

Comment: thanks, I modified the route as the start of the scaffold, I still have some difficulties to understand routes in rails but with the time, it will improve.otherwise I succeed to put everything I want in my table, but now I have to display the image who are in the bases.Its a question of path i think